# How I can get access to r_member_social?

Tags: linkedin-api

What are the steps to obtain access to it for my app?

I have tried to fetch the posts of my app users but got an error.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/lms-faq?view=li-lms-2022-12#how-do-i-get-access-to-r_member_social), access is currently closed.